# Adding product with custom option (drop down) to cart by query string?

Tags: cart, custom-options

My product (id 1234) has one custom options, called colors. The id of colors is 1234567, its a drop down and it has several options, like yellow, red and black.

Now I am trying to add that product including its custom option "yellow" with id 5678 to the cart, like this:

```
http://www.whatever.com/index.php/checkout/cart/add?product=1234&qty=1&options[1234567]=5678
```

This always results in the "There are missing custom options" error in the cart. Why? Whats wrong with my approach?

Comment: Note that adding a product with query string does not work anymore in current versions because of the new form key. See http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/32814/bypass-magentos-form-key-usage-to-allow-simple-product-to-be-added-to-cart

Answer (score 3):

it works nicely for me like this:

`http://www.whatever.com/index.php/checkout/cart/add/product/{product_id_here}?qty={qty_here}&options[{option_id_here}]={value_here}`.

If I replace `{value_here}` with an id of a custom option value that does not exist, the product still gets added to the cart, but I get an error message that the custom options are missing.  Just like you get.
It means that `5678` in your case is not a valid value.
Look in the product page source at the `value` attribute of the option you are trying to use.